# How do I create point to site connection with existing VNET in Resource manager

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have RM VNET and the address range is 192.168.3.0/24 
I have 4 VM running on it without issue.
What I noticed here is I found the IP of the VM's get changed every alternate days and because of this the APP running on the VM's are affected.

For now I have assigned Static IP for the VM's. but need to change it to Dynamic as static IP is chargable

Is there any way to assign a static IP for the VM's without charges?

Answer (score 1):

If this is referring to the free public IP assigned to you, one way to get around the cost is using a CNAME entry in your DNS pointing to your resource's FQDN. Set TTL as low as you can afford so the outside world can pick up the change fast.
Here is an article about how: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/10/11/where-is-my-dns-name-for-azure-vm-with-new-resource-manager/

If this is referring to VM's internal IP address such as 192.168.3.3, I don't believe static private IP address is chargeable.

Here is an solid article explain things:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm/